# SSH remote TensorFlow training stops when my computer goes to sleep

Tags: macos, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, tmux

I'm running `tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate` inside a Jupyter Notebook. The notebook server runs inside a tmux session on a Linux server that I connect to via `ssh` from my MacBook terminal and then browse to with a local Chrome.

Why is it that when my MacBook goes to sleep, the remote training loop is paused? In TensorBoard I can see summaries up to the evening I left the MacBook, and then nothing happened until a few days later when I opened the laptop lid again, at which point a summary pops up directly. This has happened multiple times.

Some stdout buffer is filled up when the browser isn't available anymore, I guess? If so, how can this halt training? It feels really strange. Shouldn't the notebook server just assume the client has disappeared and flush stdout anyway after a timeout?

*(yes, I'm aware that it's better to just run long scripts in the terminal instead of in a notebook environment, but this is still curious)*

Comment: Maybe you could profile on the server side to see which function call ends up blocking when you disconnect, maybe that will show whether it's somehow stream buffer related.